How to implement multirow with longtable?
I'm producing a document which looks like this:

Everything works fine, but the use of longtable and p columns to control widths properly leads to these really ugly spaces between lines.
Ideally, I would have multirows on the cells with the long titles, so that it overlaps with the content beside it. This would be equivalent to a merged cell in Excel.
How do I achieve that? I've tried multirow, but it seems to cause a lot of weird side effects with longtable.
MWE:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{siunitx} % For aligning numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables that span multiple pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{array} % For advanced table features
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For coloring table cells

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1, 1}

% siunitx setup
\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=0,
    group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits=4, % groups digits by thousands
    input-ignore={,},
    detect-all,
    tight-spacing=true,
    table-number-alignment = right % Align numbers to the right
}

% to get a proper cline
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt-#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
    \cr
    \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
% CHART

% VISI

% MISI

% PELANGGAN

% RF_NASIONAL

% RF_PROGRAM

% RF_AKTIVITI

% TABLE_SUMMARY


\begin{longtable}{
        @{}p{1cm}  % Column for 'Butiran' with fixed width
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}  % Column for OA / OS center-aligned
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]@{}
    }
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Headeri}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endfirsthead
    
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Headeri}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

\bfseries 000000 & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{\raggedright \bfseries A SOMEWHAT LONG UPPERCASED TITLE} & & 416930000 & \bfseries 429940000 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 199615000 & \bfseries 207984200 & 3123.0 & \bfseries 3123.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 188065400 & \bfseries 205758600 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 27536900 & \bfseries 14142000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 1390700 & \bfseries 1786200 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 322000 & \bfseries 269000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title (QWERTYUIOP) & & 36000000 & \bfseries 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 18170000 & \bfseries 18174200 & 233.0 & \bfseries 233.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 15045400 & \bfseries 13630000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 1964900 & \bfseries 346000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 619700 & \bfseries 1100000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \bfseries 165000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 


\end{longtable}

    
\end{document}



If you aren't tied to longtable, maybe have a look at the tabularray package. It makes merging cells and changing their alignment very easy.

BTW: what is that cline redef for?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - unfortunately I think we can't avoid longtable, because the full data in this table spans over 20 pages.

@daleif without it, the cline goes weird when mixed with longtable. See here.

I did not see any differences when I removed it.

You can do some interesting stuff with \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{\smash[b]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries A SOMEWHAT LONG UPPERCASED TITLE}}} remember to load amsmath to get \smash[b] support. Also isn't there an & to many on the other 000000 line?

@Thev tabularray also has tables which can span over multiple pages: longtblr

you can hide the depth of the parbox, or simply use the multirow package

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and needs 200 seconds to process a single 20-pages table (number is a really rough estimate that might have a 100% error margin).

@Skillmon ... and gives you enough time to fetch a coffee while it compiles :)

@daleif Will be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you make one! Tried and it works beautifully.
